# limits and even-odd functions

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Is right to say the following?

- $$\lim_{x\to x_0}{f(x)}=k\overset{f: even}{\iff}\lim_{x\to x_0}{f(-x)}=k\overset{-x=t}{\iff}\lim_{t\to -x_0}{f(t)}=k\iff\lim_{x\to -x_0}{f(x)}=k$$
- $$\lim_{x\to x_0}{f(x)}=k\overset{f: odd}{\iff}-\lim_{x\to x_0}{f(-x)}=k\overset{-x=t}{\iff}\lim_{t\to -x_0}{f(t)}=-k\iff\lim_{x\to -x_0}{f(x)}=-k$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ! Your argumentation is fine !

Comment: I suggest you use the **community wiki** button for this kind of answers.